# Duplicate Key ,reemplazar el mensaje

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una consulta rápida. Tengo una columna de una base de datos que la voy a poner como clave primaria, y se que si ingreso el dato por segunda vez el dato, saldrá un mensajito de "Duplicate entry".

La cuestión es que me gustaría cambiar ese mensaje por otro, por ejemplo : "Usted ya ha insertado este dato, intente con otro" o algo así. Alguno sabe como puedo hacer eso de alguna manera sencilla? Si es posible, que sea solo con php, porque es del cual estoy aprendiendo.

Si intento el codigo que investigue, me tira error.

```
<?php
 require_once 'configuracion.php';

 $email= "";
 $name= "";


 // authenticate code from Google OAuth Flow
 if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
 $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
 $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

 // get profile info
 $google_oauth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
 $google_account_info = $google_oauth->userinfo->get();
 $email =  $google_account_info->email;
 $name =  $google_account_info->name;

 }
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","playroom"); 

 //Registrarse con google

$m= "INSERT INTO `login`(`email`, `usuario`, `Id_usuario`)
VALUES ('$email','$name','')";

mysqli_query($conexion,$m);


mysqli_query('INSERT INTO ...');
if (mysqli_errno() == 1062) {
  print 'no way!';
}

?>
```

Muchas gracias por su atención!

Comment: Reemplazar? Dependiendo de como ejecutes el insert, puedes capturar el error o examinar qué resultado te ha dado la operación, y entonces escribir lo que quieras. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3146850/2553194) puedes encontrar ideas. Si editas tu pregunta para añadir tu código, porque no consigues hacerlo, tienes más posibilidades de obtener respuesta aquí

Comment: Yo verificaría si el dato existe antes de intentar la inserción, con algo como: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laTabla WHERE la(s)Columna(s)Unica(s)=el(los)Valor(es)Unico(s)` y luego `if($elResultadoDeMiConsultaCount === 0) { //No existe ese registro, aquí haces el INSERT } else { //Mensaje de registro duplicado }` A mi me gusta esta forma, porque si tienes una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT` en la tabla, el valor se aumenta también en las consultas fallidas ... En un contexto de mucha concurrencia / muchos fallos puedes tener saltos enormes en los auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Hay formas muy especializadas para resolver esto.

Lo mejor es, buscar el dato primero y luego, si existe, decir al usuario que ya existe.

Otra forma es, capturar el numero del error que te da la DB, y en base a ese numero decirle al usuario el problema exacto, no es mostrar el error, sino saber que el error es por el duplicado y así hacerlo saber al usuario.

Yo controlo de manera un poco más simple esos errores, cuando no se requiere de mucho y es un sistema pequeño.

```php
if (isset($_POST['formIngreso'])) {
    $nombre = $dbm->realEscapeStringFunction($_POST['nombre']);
    $email = $dbm->realEscapeStringFunction($_POST['email']);
    $phone = $dbm->realEscapeStringFunction($_POST['telefono']);
    $problema = $helpers->saltoLinea($_POST['problema']);
    /* Este es el código que en mi sistema se podría repetir */
    $codigo = $dbm->realEscapeStringFunction($_POST['codigo']);

    $codeOK = $querys->getCode($codigo)[0];

    if (!$codeOK) {
        $data = array(
            $nombre,
            $email,
            $phone,
            $problema,
            $codigo
        );
        $lastID = $querys->insertIncidencia($data)[1];

        if ($lastID) {
            // Muchas cosas
        }
    }
    else{
        echo"<script language='JavaScript'>
                alert('Código invalido !!!');
                window.history.back();
            </script>";
    }
}
```